# Need to see boot/system log from before actual session because of system shutdown after 30 minutes, only actual session log can be viewed

Tags: 22.04, uefi, shutdown, logs

Laptop is an Acer Aspire V3-772 with 8GB and Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS, Gnome 42.9 & Wayland on UEFI. The memtest could only pass once (without errors) because the laptop always crashes after close to 30 minutes. I am not sure of the integrity of the memory this way.

Because of a probable hardware problem in my friends laptop (always shutting off after half an hour), I wanted to take a look at the log from before the crash, but I can only acces the log from the actual session that is being worked at. Journalctl only shows this session and also the log viewer has no other logs than the actual session. Listing the log directory just shows 1 log.

I did read about the configuration for journalctl and did make the change from auto to persistent in that conf., but nothing changed.

B.t.w. As the shutdown also happened during memtest from Grub, I suspect the problem is not in the Ubuntu OS, because that is not loaded at that moment. Would it still be possible that a hardware failure could be revealed from a Ubuntu log?

I already ordered a new memory strip to switch with the memory in the laptop to see if that changes anything.

Power is ok, battery is full, temperature is not the problem, so looking at the logs seems to me the only way to find out what is the case.

EDIT:

> I did read about the configuration for journalctl

And that is how I know for sure that there is only 1 log available (the actual one). `sudo journalctl  --list-boots` ,`sudo journalctl -b -1`, etc. hence give the predictable results, namely: it lists just 1 boot log (the actual one) and give no result, respectively, as there are no more logs than just the one.

Whether it is a matter of disappearing logs or not, I could not say, as I never tried to acces old logs on the machine of my friend before. Maybe it always behaved like this.

EDIT-2

After some searching about why the laptop might be shutting off after 30 minutes, I encountered information pointing into the direction of a feature incorporated into Intel based machines that I never heard of before, which is called ME or IME, which stands for Intel Management Engine. This runs even when the computer has been shut off, as long as there is power (battery or otherwise). Most notably, "The ME is supposed to detect that it has been tampered with and, if this is the case, shut down the PC forcibly 30 minutes after system start."

Apparently the ME in this laptop considers it has been tampered with (I do not know how this could have happened) and decided to shut off the processor after 30 minutes.

More to be read on [Wikipedia](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Intel_Management_Engine) and [Hackaday](https://hackaday.com/2016/11/28/neutralizing-intels-management-engine/) about ME, which probably is being used by NSA and the like, if you ask me (it has acces to everything that you pc has acces to).

Comment: Because disappearing old logs is a strange thing, show, please, the output of `sudo journalctl -b -1` command.

Comment: Please see after the EDIT in my original question for the answer to your question alokym

Answer (score 0):

Read `man journalctl`. Use `sudo journalctl  --list-boots`. Use `sudo journalctl -b -1` to see the logs of the previous boot, `sudo journalctl  -b -2` for the one before that, etc.

I use this alias to format date/time information the way `--since=` and `--before=` accept, using the full power of GNU `date`. Read `man date`

```
alias tsjou="date '+%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'"
```

I have more `journalctl` hints in my AskUbuntu profile, click on my userid.