# How to install Intel(R) Management Engine Interface (Intel(R) MEI) Also known as HECI in Ubuntu?

Tags: drivers, 22.04, shutdown

My Ubuntu laptop shuts off after 30 minutes because (at least this was my conclusion after some research) the Intel Management Engine (IME) decided that its integrity was at play, so eventually I downloaded and ran the CSME-Version-Detection-Tool from Intel.

FYI: the system does not suffer from hardware problems of any kind, this shutting of is a feature (!).

After running this tool, my suspicion was confirmed that the shutting off after half an hour indeed was caused by something that had to do with the IME.

The output in terminal mentioned:

*** Risk Assessment ***
Detection Error: This system may be vulnerable,
either the Intel(R) MEI/TXEI driver is not installed
(available from your system manufacturer)
or the system manufacturer does not permit access
to the ME/TXE from the host driver.

The tool also produced a log which mentioned the following:

- Manufacturer: Acer Model: Aspire V3-772 Processor Name: Intel(R)
  Core(TM) i7-4702MQ CPU @ 2.20GHz OS Version: Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
  (5.15.0-83-generic) SPS: Failed to send/receive message over HECI
  using MMIO Status: HECI_NOT_INSTALLED Tool Stopped

I did a search into what HECI was supposed to mean and I found that it stands for: Host Embedded Controller Interface, which is not to be found in Linux, because in Linux this is called "Intel(R) Management Engine Interface (Intel(R) MEI)".

At the moment I am stuck with a laptop that shuts off exactly 30 minutes after booting, because of this missing interface, so I want to have this fixed, but I do not know how to do this.

So, please help me out when you are knowledgeable in this field.

I posted a somewhat related question [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1484498/need-to-see-boot-system-log-from-before-actual-session-because-of-system-shutdow). There you can also find some links with information concerning the Intel Management Engine.

EDIT

Today (sept 8th) something strange, but also something lucky happened: the laptop stayed on for more than the 30 minutes!
I have no idea why (well I have some guesses, which I will go into below), but there was no action from my part involved, that is for sure.

After noting that this time the laptop did not shut off after the 30 minute grace period that ME allows the unlucky user that is affected by this, I decided to run the CSME-Version-Detection-Tool again to see if anything had changed according to this tool.

Indeed, the output differed from the one before and now it said in my terminal:

*** Risk Assessment ***
Based on the analysis performed by this tool: The system is not supported
Firmware versions of Intel(R) ME 3.x thru 10.x,
Intel(R) TXE 1.x thru 2.x and Intel(R) Server Platform Services 1.x thru 2.x are no longer supported,
thus were not assessed for the vulnerabilities/CVEs listed in these Security Advisories.
There is no new release planned for these versions.

and the associated log noted:

Engine: Intel(R) ME
Version: 9.0.3.1347
Status: NOT_SUPPORTED
Tool Stopped

So it seems that the whole ME had disappeared for one reason or another...

I checked the log from this session and saw something that might be related to the change in the firmware which seemed relevant to ME

08:09:59 systemd: Started Firmware update daemon.

08:09:59 fwupd: 06:09:59:0244 FuPluginPciMei       ME family not supported for 0:9.0.3.1347

Maybe systemd solved the problem for me with starting a Firmware update deamon that took care of it?

Anyhow: the system is again up and running normally.

EDIT-2

One week later (sept 15th) the problem is back again, i.e. shutting off after 30 minutes.
The CSME-Version-Detection-Tool from Intel again reports the system as being vulnerable, etc.

I tried the suggestion for a solution in my own answer below, but to no avail. Running fwupd did not resolve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Based on what I described in the EDIT-section of my original question, i.e. when my problem was resolved, I think that the answer to this problem lies within the use of the Firmware Update daemon by systemd. That is why I suggest to anyone experiencing a similar problem with the shutting off after exactly 30 minutes after booting to check the Intel Management Engine.

I did this as described above with the CSME-Version-Detection-Tool, that can be found [here](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/download/19392/intel-converged-security-and-management-engine-version-detection-tool-intel-csmevdt.html) .

This can give you a confirmation if the IME is involved in the behavior of your system.

Because my problem seems to be solved after a firmware update invoked by systemd during booting, it seems logical to do this yourself. I suggest to read [this description](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/driver-api/mei/mei.html) on the Intel MEI driver on the Website with the Linux Kernel documentation (kernel.org)

Wether the above information on kernel.org is digestible or not for you, at the following link to LinuxOPsys you will find a description on [How to Update Firmware on Ubuntu using fwupd](https://linuxopsys.com/topics/update-firmware-on-ubuntu-using-fwupd) , it seems to me be the best approach in solving this problem.

EDIT

Unfortunately this is not the correct answer as I found out a week after the problem seemed resolved. In the original question above I report on the disappointing result of running fwupd.